# Can not download jars when building scala project with sbteclipse?

Tags: scala, sbteclipse

[image]

As shown in the picture, when I build scala project with sbteclipse and import to eclipse, when changing **build.sbt** , jars are downloaded to my computer but not to scalaProject. I do not know why. Can someone help me?

```
scala version: 2.11.8
sbt version: 0.13.15
stbeclipse:5.1.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're using the *Scala IDE* plugin for *Eclipse*, correct?

The *sbteclipse SBT* plugin merely provides a command to generate an *Eclipse Scala* project from the *SBT* build. Before using *Eclipse*, you're supposed to issue the following command (from the command line) to *SBT*:

```
sbt eclipse
```

This should generate the project files for your *Eclipse* project. After executing this command, you can open your project using *Eclipse* (with the *Scala IDE* plugin).

Note that, at present, the *Scala IDE Eclipse* plugin does not support *SBT* build files. That is, if you change your *SBT* build file, then *Eclipse* will be none the wiser, until you re-run the above command.

You might want to consider switching to [*IntelliJ IDEA*](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (instead of *Eclipse*) which has a full-featured *Scala* plugin that fully supports *SBT* builds, including downloading any dependencies. For my money (both IDEs are free) *IntelliJ* is light-years ahead of *Eclipse* for *Scala* development.

Comment: ok,thang you . i have solve this problem.  every time i add new dependiency, i should reload end re eclipse the scala project builded by stbeclipse